# Reading in parallel from multiple hard drives

Tags: parallel-processing, hard-drive

I am writing an application that deals with lots of data (gigabytes). I am considering splitting the data onto multiple hard drives and reading it in parallel. I am wondering what kind of limitations I will run into--for example, is it possible to read from 4 or 8 hard drives in parallel, and will I get approximately 4 or 8 times the performance if disk I/O is the limiting factor? What should I look out for? Pointers to relevant docs are also appreciated--Google didn't turn up much.

EDIT: I should point out that I've looked at RAID, but the performance wasn't as good as I was hoping for. I am planning on writing this myself in C/C++.

Comment: "Gigabytes" is not really lots of data, IMO; I would start thinking about this when you get to terabytes, or at least 100 GB or so.  Before that level, efficient data structures are far more important than data partitioning.

Comment: Look at RAID again. Specifically, RAID 0 or 10. You are wasting your time, because RAID does exactly what you want and better.

Answer (score 2):

Well splitting data and reading from 4 to 8 drives in parallel would not jump the throughput by 4 to 8 times. There are other factors which you need to consider.

1. If you reading data in the application, then threads might be required to read data from different harddisks.
2. Windows provide overlapped and non-overlapped method of reading and writing data to hdd. See if using that increases the throughput. Same way *nux would also have read/write methods.
3. On a single core/processor threads appear to run in parallel but its sequentially underlying. With multicore multiple threads can be read in parallel but generally OS decides what to run and when to run. So having so many threads to read might decrease performance than increase.
4. If you check specs of any harddisk, you would see it gives random access time and sequential access time. So based on you data you may want to check these parameters.
5. When you spliting data into different drives you need to keep in mind that your application would require syncronization of how to populate data into meaningful information. If you using threads, additionally threads should be in sync.
6. You may get state of the art harddisk with high data read/write speeds but you other hardware may be the weak link. So you may be using a low-end motherboard or RAM which may not let you get the best of the speeds.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to use real RAID, you better at least use multiple hard drive controllers, otherwise you won't see much performance gain at all.  One controller can't do lots of concurrent IO so it will quickly become the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are talking about the concept of data striping.  This is commonly used for RAID implementations.  You may want to look into one of the software RAID solutions available for most operating systems.  An advantage is if you can use raid to your advantage and add parity (ability to lose a drive and not your data)

This would give you the benefits of RAID without having to try to deal with it yourself.  You could do it on a database level as well with data files spread across the drives, but this adds complexity.

You will stream data faster.  Drives are only so fast and if your I/O channel can handle more go for it.  There's also seek times to take into account...  Probably not a big deal based on your app description.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to be OK with looking at reconfiguring the drives, how about SSDs?
They run rings around any mechanical drives (up around 200+GB/sec read, 150+GB/sec write).

Are you sequentially reading the data, or randomly?
How many GB are you expecting?